# Number of files counter

Tags: centos, files

I have a CentOS 7 with postfix.

E-mails are stored in:

Var/vmail/DomainName/*Usernames*/Maildir/.Junk/

The only variable is the *Usernames* that correspond to each mailbox.

I could use a script to count the files for each address junk folder and put them into a centralized text file.

What would be the simplest way to do this so that I can have an output like:

Username1: nn

Username2: nn

.............

Where nn is the number of files in the junk folder of the respective user.

Comment: can you post the output of ls -lrt Var/vmail/DomainName/Usernames/Maildir/.Junk

Comment: Using ls -lrt  /var/vmail/vmail1/DomainName/Username1/Maildir/.Junk/new/ outputs: total 40 and lists permissions, dates and names of the 3 files that are in the junk/new/ folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this helps ?

```
#!/bin/bash

for UserName in /var/vmail/DomainName/*
do
    PATH="${UserName}/Maildir/.Junk"
    Num_Of_Files=$(find ${PATH} -type f | wc -l)
    echo "${UserName} : ${Num_Of_Files}"
done
```

Comment: line 8: find: command not found
line 8: wc: command not found

Comment: replace find and wc with this

/usr/bin/find
/usr/bin/wc

Comment: Putting that to both find and wc worked, but now I get the main path doubled (and invalid path due to that). And a wierd " â" character at start and end of path. Fixed that, it was a lowercase at fault.

Comment: do we have sub direcotry inside the .Junk ?

add -maxdepth 1 in the find command to scan only 1 level

Comment: No need for depth, it's fine now. However, do correct in your answer by removing /var/vmail/DomainName/ from the PATH=, or else the path will double (and I'll mark it as correct).

Comment: yes.. you are correct.. i modified the answer..